# How do i turn my wireless adapter into an access point?

Tags: linux, wireless-access-point

I want the wireless adapter on my linux box to behave as an access point. I also want the wireless network to run over WPA2 for security. I also want it to serve out addresses to other devices which would join the network.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: *`man hostapd`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chris S said, you will need to use the `hostapd` daemon. There is one major caveat though; your wireless card must support "Master" mode in order to act like an access point. A somewhat current compatibility list is available here: http://hostap.epitest.fi/hostapd/

Comment: Actually, if you don't like the idea of writing a configuration file for `hostapd`, the popular NetworkManager tool also supports managing an AP now, but this is not available through its GUI tools; it requires a manual tweak in its configuration file for `mode=ap`. Reference in Russian: http://www.altlinux.org/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.83.D0.BF.D0.B0_.D0.B2_NetworkManager